# Help recovering Oracle Datafile :selecting from or loading data into an oracle 11g r2 ED Datatabase: ORA-00376 & ORA-01110

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

A user created a datafile with size 200M and when the datafile was created it appeared in the OS as a Zero Kilobytes file. And then the user tried to drop the datafile but after that using query: alter database datafile 'G:\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\RVAS\RATEL140.DBF' offline;

But when ever they try to load data into the database or query the database the following error is thrown: ORA-00376: file 151 cannot be read at this time
ORA-01110: data file 151: 'G:\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\RVAS\RATEL140.DBF'
00376. 00000 -  "file %s cannot be read at this time"
*Cause:    attempting to read from a file that is not readable. Most likely
the file is offline.
*Action:   Check the state of the file. Bring it online

To try and fix that i have tried to make the datafile online but the error below came: ora-01157 & ora-01110.

I have also tried to recover the file but the following error comes: SQL> recover datafile 151;
ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
ORA-01110: data file 151: 'G:\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\RVAS\RATEL140.DBF'
ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 151 - see DBWR trace file
ORA-01110: data file 151: 'G:\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\RVAS\RATEL140.DBF'

Please help.

Comment: And what does that trace file say?  Regarding the "zero kilobytes": no space left?  Or did the file exist before trying to create it from within Oracle.  Do you have many users with permission to create datafiles?

Comment: What i have gathered now is that the guy created 4 datafiles named ratel140.dbf to ratel143.dbf so he says after the files got created files ratel141.dbf to ratel143.dbf came with sizes 200M and then he realised that he needed bigger datafiles. He also says file ratel140 came with zero kbs. So he decided to do offline drop all the four files and then did shift-delete all the 4 files and files ratel141.dbf to ratel143.dbf got removed permanently from OS. File ratel140.dbf refused to be deleted and is still visible in OS.

Comment: The OS refusing to delete that file could be because that file is in use.  If I were you I would invite a DBA to come and have a look at your problem.  Do you have a valid backup from before when the troubles started?  Don't take one now!

Comment: The DBWR trace file???